# Not able to fetch documents in solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr 6.6.0, while importing data into solr i am getting following error.

[image]

My schema and solr config looks fine.
What could be the possible cause? Please help.

Comment: Is the document with the id mentioned is in solr?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti i am importing data from database. the id above in picture and some more ids after that are not getting imported to solr due to above error. unfortunately, i am not able to decode the error though. u have any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure on it. Is there any stack trace that is missing...I would suggest to get the record from the database for that id and try inserting it to solr... That might give you the clue where it is failing ...